# Why did the Philadelphia Flyers make Gritty their mascot?

Tags: trivia, ice-hockey

Why did the Flyers change/upgrade their mascot to Gritty? I tried searching on many news websites, but they seem to focus on the responses that those on social media left, rather than why.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes, brands change their brand/mascot just because the old one is played out or the current management finds it uninteresting.

And really, a few years later I would say the gritty experiment worked. Its one of the most spoken of mascots of the league while I could not even name the previous Flyers mascot.